# Regular expression for browser Url

Tags: javascript, regex, url

I am new to JavaScript

i need a regular expression which

allows both of this forms

for example :

1. http://www.google.com
2. www.google.com

Comment: How about `google.com` and `to`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best regular expression to check if a string is a valid URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url)

Answer (score 1):

```
var url_pattern = new RegExp("((ftp|http|https)(:\/\/))?([a-zA-Z0-9]+[.]{1}){2}[a-zA-z0-9]+(\/{1}[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*\/?", "i");

return url_pattern.test(url);
```

Comment: Hey chris i have one more question 

I have used the code for same url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2899454/regular-expression-for-browser-url its not working

Answer (score 0):

`(ftp|http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?`

This works quite well.

Comment: Thanks for the reply 

I am using same expression but its not allowing this form of url

www.google.com

Comment: Interesting. I am using that very pattern in a few of my applications, and it has always worked really well. Are you sure there isn't an error in your code?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `((ftp|http|https):\/\/)?...` ?

Answer (score 0):

I've just written up a blog post on recognising URLs in most used formats such as:

`www.google.com`
`http://www.google.com`
`mailto:somebody@google.com`
`somebody@google.com`
`www.url-with-querystring.com/?url=has-querystring`

The regular expression used is `/((([A-Za-z]{3,9}:(?:\/\/)?)(?:[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)?[A-Za-z0-9.-]+|(?:www.|[-;:&=\+\$,\w]+@)[A-Za-z0-9.-]+)((?:\/[\+~%\/.\w-_]*)?\??(?:[-\+=&;%@.\w_]*)#?(?:[\w]*))?)/` however I would recommend you got to http://blog.mattheworiordan.com/post/13174566389/url-regular-expression-for-links-with-or-without-the to see a complete working example along with an explanation of the regular expression in case you need to extend or tweak it.

Answer (score 0):

`^((?:(?:https?|ftp):)?\/\/?)?(?:\S+(?::\S*)?@)?(?:(?!10(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!127(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!169\.254(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!192\.168(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!172\.(?:1[6-9]|2\d|3[0-1])(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+-?)*[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+-?)*[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}]{2,})))(?::\d{2,5})?(?:\/[^\s]*)?$`

**Test it!** https://regex101.com/r/qQ8uV6/1

Extracted from *In search of the perfect URL validation regex* https://mathiasbynens.be/demo/url-regex (modified it a bit).

credits to [@diegoperini](https://twitter.com/diegoperini).

If you test it in JavaScript, you'll get a nice

> ParseError: Error parsing regular expression: Invalid regular expression
>
> ....
>
> Range out of order in character class

You need to replace `\x{xxxx}` for `\uxxxx`. So in **JavaScript** it'll be:

`^(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/)?(?:\S+(?::\S*)?@)?(?:(?!10(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!127(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!169\.254(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!192\.168(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!172\.(?:1[6-9]|2\d|3[0-1])(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\u00a1-\ufff0-9]+-?)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+-?)*[a-z\u00a1-\uffff0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z\u00a1-\uffff]{2,})))(?::\d{2,5})?(?:\/[^\s]*)?$`

Just like stated in [JavaScript Unicode Regex - Range out of order in character class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29028756/javascipt-unicode-regex-range-out-of-order-in-character-class)