# Check if a string starts with http using Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I've been searching all over for an answer to this and all of the answers I've found haven't been in JavaScript.

I need a way, in javascript, to check if a string starts with http, https, or ftp. If it doesn't start with one of those I need to prepend the string with `http://`. indexOf won't work for me I don't think as I need either http, https or ftp. Also I don't want something like `google.com/?q=http://google.com` to trigger that as being valid as it doesn't start with an http whereas indexOf would trigger that as being true (if I'm not entirely mistaken).

The closest PHP regex I've found is this:

```
function addhttp($url) {
   if (!preg_match("~^(?:f|ht)tps?://~i", $url)) {
      $url = "http://" . $url;
   }
   return $url;
}
```

[Source: How to add http if its not exists in the url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762061/how-to-add-http-if-its-not-exists-in-the-url)

I just don't know how to convert that to javascript. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Shamefully confusion of javascript and java deleted

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regular expression for browser Url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2899454/regular-expression-for-browser-url)

Answer (score 112, accepted):

```
export const getValidUrl = (url = "") => {
    let newUrl = window.decodeURIComponent(url);
    newUrl = newUrl.trim().replace(/\s/g, "");

    if(/^(:\/\/)/.test(newUrl)){
        return `http${newUrl}`;
    }
    if(!/^(f|ht)tps?:\/\//i.test(newUrl)){
        return `http://${newUrl}`;
    }

    return newUrl;
};
```

Tests:

```
expect(getValidUrl('https://www.test.com')).toBe('https://www.test.com');
expect(getValidUrl('http://www.test.com')).toBe('http://www.test.com');
expect(getValidUrl('    http   :    /  /  www.test.com')).toBe('http://www.test.com');
expect(getValidUrl('ftp://www.test.com')).toBe('ftp://www.test.com');
expect(getValidUrl('www.test.com')).toBe('http://www.test.com');
expect(getValidUrl('://www.test.com')).toBe('http://www.test.com');
expect(getValidUrl('http%3A%2F%2Fwww.test.com')).toBe('http://www.test.com');
expect(getValidUrl('www    .  test.com')).toBe('http://www.test.com');
```

Comment: I would recommend adding check for 'url' value in order to avoid returning 'http://' when no value (or empty) string is provided: if (url && !/^(f|ht)tps?:\/\//i.test(url))

Comment: I always get "undefined" back. Can you provide a codepen or jsfiddle?

Answer (score 40):

This should work:

```
var pattern = /^((http|https|ftp):\/\/)/;

if(!pattern.test(url)) {
    url = "http://" + url;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JnKVw/)

Answer (score 20):

```
var url = "http://something.com"
if( url.indexOf("http") == 0 ) {
    alert("yeah!");
} else {
    alert("No no no!");
}
```

Comment: trim the url as it if you have `SPACE http` than it there is problem :P

Comment: what if the url is like: "javascript://somethinghttp.com"

Comment: In that case doesn't really matter because the question is "how to know if a string starts with http"

Answer (score 5):

Non-Regex declarative way:

```
const hasValidUrlProtocol = (url = '') => 
    ['http://', 'https://', 'ftp://'].some(protocol => url.startsWith(protocol))
```

Comment: This is a good answer! +1 for declarative! But do you need the `Boolean` here? Doesn't `.some()` return a boolean already?

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
var re = /^(http|https|ftp)/
```

Answer (score 3):

Refining previous answers a bit more, I used `new RegExp(...)` to avoid messy escapes, and also added an optional `s`.

```js
var pattern = new RegExp('^(https?|ftp)://');

if(!pattern.test(url)) {
    url = "http://" + url;
}
```

```js
var pattern = new RegExp('^(https?|ftp)://');


console.log(pattern.test('http://foo'));
console.log(pattern.test('https://foo'));
console.log(pattern.test('ftp://foo'));
console.log(pattern.test('bar'));
```

Answer (score 2):

Using startsWith which is easier to read, just keep in mind that is case-sensitive (hence the conversion of input to lower case)

```
const startsWithProtocol = (s: string): boolean =>
      ['https://', 'http://', 'ftp://'].some(protocol => s.toLowerCase().startsWith(protocol))
```

Answer (score 1):

Best readability I'd say is to use `.startsWith('theString')`.

The code below checks for both `http://`, `https://` and `ftp://` and sets `okUrl` to a boolean true if any of them comply, by using the `||` which means `or`.

When you know if the url contains none of those strings, then just just add `http://` to the start of the string either with literals (`${}`)

```
let url = 'google.com'
const okUrl = url.startsWith('http://') || url.startsWith('https://') || url.startsWith('ftp://')


if (! okUrl) url = `http://${url}`
// => 'http://google.com'
```

or with simple string concat, which can be done in various ways, for example:

```
url = 'http://' + url
```

Read more about it, and test it, here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith